# How can I initialize each element to zero in a global array defined in LLVM using C++?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, llvm

How can I initialize a global array in LLVM?

I'd like to initialize a global array in LLVM, I have the following in my .ll file:

`@myArray = internal local_unnamed_addr  global [1024 x i64],align 8`

I'm trying to initialize each element to zero in my cpp code  but it just seg faults here:

```
const auto myArray = module_->getGlobalVariable("myArray");
  llvm::ArrayType* ArrayTy_0 =
      llvm::ArrayType::get(llvm::IntegerType::get(module_->getContext(), 64), 1024);

  llvm::ConstantAggregateZero* const_array_2 =
      llvm::ConstantAggregateZero::get(ArrayTy_0);
  myArray->setInitializer(const_array_2);
```

Comment: If it segfaults, you have to find out where. You can do that now or next time you have a problem. Build LLVM with assertions enabled, that generally provides an early error message *and* a precise stack trace. RelWithDeb is my preference.